# Java EE authentication: how to capture login event?

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee

Given an authentication mechanism of type FORM defined for a Java web app, how do you capture the *login performed* event before being redirected to requested resource? Is there any kind of listener where I can put my code to be executed when a user logs in?

I feel like defining a filter is not the best solution, as the filter is linked to the resource and would be invoked even when the user is already authenticated and asking for a resource. I'm wondering if there's some class/method triggered only by login event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such event in Java EE. Yet. As part of [JSR375](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=375), container managed security will be totally reworked as it's currently [scattered](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/10/how-servlet-containers-all-implement.html) across different container implemantations and is not cross-container compatible. This is outlined in this [Java EE 8 Security API](http://www.slideshare.net/a_kosowski/devoxx-fr-ee8jsr375securityapiv1) presentation.

There's already a reference implementation of Security API in progress, [Soteria](https://github.com/javaee-security-spec/soteria), developed by among others my fellow Arjan Tijms. With the new Security API, CDI will be used to fire authentication events which you can just `@Observes`. Discussion on the specification took place in [this mailing list thread](https://java.net/projects/javaee-security-spec/lists/jsr375-experts/archive/2015-03/message/61). It's not yet concretely implemented in Soteria.

Until then, assuming `FORM` based authentication whereby the user principal is internally stored in the session, your best bet is manually checking in a servlet filter if there's an user principal present in the request while your representation of the logged-in user is absent in the HTTP session.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    String username = request.getRemoteUser();

    if (username != null && request.getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
        // First-time login. You can do your thing here.
        User user =  yourUserService.find(username);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Do note that registering a filter on `/j_security_check` is not guaranteed to work as a decent container will handle it internally before the first filters are hit, for obvious security reasons (user-provided filters could manipulate the request in a bad way, either accidentally or awarely).

If you however happen to use a Java EE server uses the [Undertow](http://undertow.io/) servletcontainer, such as [WildFly](http://wildfly.org), then there's a more clean way to hook on its internal notification events and then fire custom CDI events. This is fleshed out in [this blog](http://jdevelopment.nl/bridging-undertows-authentication-events-cdi/) of Arjan Tijms. As shown in the blog, you can ultimately end up with a CDI bean like this:

```
@SessionScoped
public class SessionAuthListener implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void onAuthenticated(@Observes AuthenticatedEvent event) {
        String username = event.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        // Do something with name, e.g. audit, 
        // load User instance into session, etc
    }

    public void onLoggedOut(@Observes LoggedOutEvent event) {
        // take some action, e.g. audit, null out User, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate SO for not giving the chance to upvote more than once! Said that, Undertow solution will make your webapp not fully portable, that's something I'm trying to avoid right now. At this point, adding a filter for a range of URLS is probably the solution I'm going to apply, I was just a bit worried for the overhead that could come from such a widely applied filter, but at the end of the day most of the time it will just result in a not verified if condition... do you think it would be an "acceptable overhead"?

Comment: :) SO has the concept of [bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). Moreover, some users have a wishlist or donate link on their profile. As to the overhead, this is really negligible. A few nanoseconds perhaps. There are in a full fledged web application way much better things to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Servlet filter on the `j_security_check` URI. This filter will not be invoke on every request, but only on the login request.

Check the following page - [Developing servlet filters for form login processing](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tsec_servlet.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-12-2-7-3-0&lang=en) - this works in WebSphere App Server, and WebSphere Liberty profile.

Having such filter:

```
@WebFilter("/j_security_check")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
...
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Filter called 1: " +((HttpServletRequest)request).getUserPrincipal());
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
        System.out.println("Filter called 2: " + ((HttpServletRequest)request).getUserPrincipal());

}
```

gives the following output:

```
// on incorrect login
Filter called 1: null
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID user1. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
Filter called 2: null

// on correct login
Filter called 1: null
Filter called 2: WSPrincipal:user1
```

UPDATE

Other possible way to do it is to use your own servlet for login, change the action in your login page to that servlet and use `request.login()` method. This is servlet API so should work even in Wildfly and you have full control over login. You just need to find out how wildfly passes the originally requested resource URL (WebSphere does it via cookie).

Servlet pseudo code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user = request.getParameter("j_username");
    String password = request.getParameter("j_password");
    try {
        request.login(user, password);
        // redirect to requested resource
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // login failed - redirect to error login page
    }
```

Comment: This sounds a good idea and in theory should work, but for me it's not, and I don't know why. Filter seems not to be triggered by `j_security_check` call. For example, a filter with `url-pattern` set to `*` is being invoked for every unprotected resource, but it's not executed for a login with wrong password, for example. Or is executed only once (for the resource URI, not `j_security_check` URI) when successfully loggin in. Wildfly 8 here. [relevant link](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=32640)

Comment: @LuigiCortese I've used following servlet mapping `@WebFilter("/j_security_check")` and filter is only called when you submit your login form. It works perfectly fine in WebSphere Liberty

Comment: @BalusC your comment is incorrect, or incorrectly formed. My filter is correctly invoked on the j_security_check. So I dont really understand what you meant by "internally"

Comment: Then that's a Liberty-specific feature/quirk. This should definitely not be relied upon across containers.

Comment: The behaviour depends on the server/container, no general assumptions can be made. On Wildfly/JBoss this won't work, on WebSphere it will

Comment: This technique is not portable as many servlet container implementations intercept the `j_security_check` before any filter is invoked.

Comment: @LuigiCortese You could try also solution with servlet, unless you already implemented one suggested by BalusC

Comment: @balusc BalusC is right. j_security_check *MUST* be processed before the FIRST filter is accessed. The Servlet spec is not overly clear on this, but it's in 13.6.3. If a protected web resource is accessed, it can only be activated if the user is authenticated. As long as j_security_check is not processed, the user is not authenticated. Key insight is that when a filter is called, the web resource must be activated, which is not allowed if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: @dextermeyers As you wrote, spec is not clear on that. And j_security_check is UNPROTECTED resource, so it doesn't require authentication, and also running filter on unprotected resource doesnt require authentication, so I dont follow your logic, why filter on j_security_check would require authentication.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't overly clear, sorry. What I meant is that j_security_check is coupled to FORM in Servlet spec, and that piece of code must be executed before all filters (it forwards to the login resource that is specified). Now technically, j_security_check could be implemented with a vendor mapped Servlet, but the spec does not say j_security_check has to be a web resource at all, that's the main problem. Since FORM *MUST* be checked before, and j_security_check is part of FORM, it's very likely (I know vague), that j_security_check is also executed before all filters.

Comment: @dextermeyers I'm sorry, but your explanations are just too vague. :-). Nowhere in the spec it says that j_security_check must be processed before filters, so lets just agree that it is vendor dependent, as for WebSphere it is perfectly working solution.;-)

Comment: It's the other way around unfortunately.  Because it does not mandate that j_security_check is a web resource, you can't assume it will be. So a filter happens to work in Liberty (let's not talk about WebSphere anymore ;)), but as you said that's vendor specific. So for *Java EE* the answer is, again unfortunately, not correct. Had it been a Liberty specific question, then it was correct. Hope my comment is more clear now ;)

Comment: @dextermeyers How about custom login servlet part of the answar, that should be correct for Java EE also, as it is utilizing only Servlet API.

Comment: With that part, as you mention, getting the original request is non standard again (most servers store it in the session, but a cookie of course works too). At that point you'd almost be better off writing your own custom authentication mechanism (not easy), but see links BalusC posted.